# Tailwind Inline color decorators are not working with CSS variables

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, visual-studio-code, tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind CSS with CSS variables for styling in my Next 13 project. What I noticed is that the color previewers/decorators that appear when you define a color are not appearing in my class names. The color previewers really help to see which color is being applied.

The important thing to note is that it is working when I use the default colors of tailwind like `text-red-500` or even for arbitrary values like `text-[red]`. But when I use a color that is defined as a CSS variable the color box does not appear but the CSS is applied without any problem. The code and pictures are attached below that should give you a better idea.

global.css file code:

```
:root{
     --background: 222.2 84% 4.9%;
 }
```

tailwind.config.js file code:

```
theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        background: 'hsl(var(--background))'
      }
    }
  }
```

As you can see in the pic below the IntelliSense for normal tailwind colors is working correctly but for colors defined with CSS variable is not showing the decorator.

[image]

I have tried it using hex color instead of hsl but it doesn't work also. I am using the latest version of both Tailwind and Tailwind IntelliSense. I have also looked at some of the GitHub issues but in them the extension was not working in my case it is working but not for CSS variables. Is there a way to make it work??

Comment: This would be near impossible for the extension to do, due to the nature of CSS variables. The value of the CSS variable could be changed in multitude of different ways that the intellisense would not have access to or would be difficult to code for, and which could also change at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Saimarshadd. You have written all of the code correctly, but the only thing you need to correct is the HSL syntax value in root variables. Follow the blow points to write the hsl color value in proper syntax.

In CSS, a color can be specified using hue, saturation, and lightness (HSL) in the form:

**hsl(hue, saturation, lightness)**

1. Hue is a degree on the color wheel from 0 to 360. 0 is red, 120 is green, and 240 is blue.
2. Saturation is a percentage value. 0% means a shade of gray, and 100% is the full color.
3. Lightness is also a percentage. 0% is black, 50% is neither light or dark, 100% is white

**Solution**

You need to use `deg` instead of `%` in hue. Just write HSL color value like this.

```
:root {
 --background: 222.2deg 88.47% 45.62%;
}
```

Comment: Hey Vivek, Thanks for the reply. But, as I mentioned In my question above, the code is working fine the main problem was the extension not showing the preview of the color being applied. There is no mistake in the way I applied hsl values, you don't need to mention deg. You can read more about it in the tailwind docs https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#using-css-variables.